# Angular Reactive Forms - Add ng-invalid to another field (like it does with [formGroup] and [formControl]

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive forms.

I noticed that when a tag has [formGroup]="mygroup" it adds the group validation .ng-invalid .ng-valid .ng-touched etc... to that html tag.   Same happens for formControlName="" and formGroupName="".

I am trying to make the fields label turn red when it's invalid.  Is there any way to add those CSS classes to the field's  tag?

```
<label form="myfield">This is a label</label>
                          <mat-form-field class="col3 no-bottom dense" id="myfield" appearance="fill">
                            <mat-label>field label</mat-label>
                            <input matInput placeholder="Year" mask="0000" formControlName="myfieldname">
                          </mat-form-field>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What if you trigger the class `ng-invalid` on your label ?

```html
<label 
  form="myfield" 
  [class.ng-invalid]="myFormGroup.controls['myfieldname'].invalid">
    This is a label
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I guess that works, but have to write this out for every label in a huge form.

Comment: In this case, use the generated class `ng-invalid` of the form, to cible every `label`.

Comment: But the ng-invalid generated on the form  will give all labels ng-invalid, even though one field may be invalid. did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Arh .. Yeah you’re right ! Didn’t think about that. Well .. I don’t think I have a better solution for now :/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a directive, that way one can do:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[vControlName].[validate],[vControl].[validate]',
})
export class FieldLabelControl {
  @Input() vControlName?: string
  @Input() validate?:boolean|string = false
  @Input() vControl?: FormControl

  constructor(@Optional() private parent: ControlContainer, @Optional() private parentForm: FormGroupDirective) {}

  @HostBinding('class.invalid')
  get invalid() {
    this.validate = !!this.validate || this.validate === '' || this.validate === 'true'
    if (!this.validate) return false;
    if (this.vControl && this.vControl.invalid) return true
    else if (this.vControlName != null && this.vControlName !== '' && this.parent)
      return !!(this.parent.control?.get(this.vControlName)?.invalid)
    else
      return false
  }
```